# Azure devops code change is not synced in github

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I imported my git project to a newly created project in Azure DevOps. After my project has been synced I made a dummy change on the master branch which I commit and push immediately.

That change is not being recognized on github on the same (master) branch.

Am I missing the obvious, the imported github code to azure devops will not be in sync after I made a change in azure devops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a sync, its a one time import, for sync you'd have to create a build that would pull code from your Azure Devops and push to github (or vice versa).

Alternatively you can just use Azure Devops to pull code from Github and build it